# (...) doesn't exist in the current context - Gradient and others brushes

Tags: c#, winforms, gradient, brush

I saw a way to make a form's background color Gradient.

That was done by a GradientBrush but when I try that, it says it doesn't exist.

I wrote like this:

```
GradientBrush something = New GradientBrush();
```

In the output window I see the "doesn't exist in the current context" error.

Comment: Add the code you are trying to do.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! - As the `GradientBrush` is not recognized I assum Winforms. See my answer how to create a  simple gradient in Winforms!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `winforms Form` you could do this:

```
using  System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
...
...

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (LinearGradientBrush br = new
            LinearGradientBrush(Form1.ClientRectangle, Color.Wheat, Color.DimGray, 0f))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, Form1.ClientRectangle);
}
```

To get rid of flicker set the form to `DoubleBuffered = true;`

For more colors use the multicolor overload of the `LinearGradientBrush`! For an example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339553/fill-panel-with-gradient-in-three-colors/30341521?s=2|0.5452#30341521)!

[image]

If the background is fixed you may consider creating a Bitmap with the gradient. Perfect if the user will not resize the form..:

```
Bitmap form1Back = new Bitmap(form1.ClientSize.Width, form1.ClientSize.Height);
using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(form1Back))
using (LinearGradientBrush br = new 
       LinearGradientBrush( form2.ClientRectangle, Color.Wheat, Color.DimGray, 0f))
    G.FillRectangle(br, form2.ClientRectangle);
form1.BackgroundImage = form1Back;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add the `System.Windows.Media` nampespace to your application 
 simply add.

```
using System.Windows.Media;
```

Then the compiler would recoginize this class.

Goodluck.