# N-point gradient brush polygon fill

Tags: c#, gdi+, linear-gradients

Is it possible to fill a N-gon, for example a 4 point polygon, that has a different color at each point and have GDI+ to do the color blending? I am looking for something like this:

[image: 3-point gradient]

but for 4 point shapes.

Comment: No, this will not work in one stroke. You can use a series of strokes and fill it pixel row by row.. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339553/fill-panel-with-gradient-in-three-colors/30341521?s=2|0.5512#30341521) for a simple example. (See the bottom of the answer!) For n-point polygon (assuming convex shape) you woud have to frist create a set of gradients that go along all egdes. Then you can use them to create the brushes needed to fill..

Comment: I get your idea, but for a not axis - aligned shape I am not sure if this will work. I would expect blank pixels. I think I need a rasterizer here that will go through all the pixels.

Comment: No, you would have to go through all pixel rows, one by one, each stroke going horizontally. Build two Color Arrays, each the size of the total height and fill them by going through the relevant edges.. along the way store the x-values in two more arrays. Then use each color pair to draw the lines..Axis-alignment should not be an issue, no matter which axis you think of..

Comment: A trivial way to do it is to fill the bounding rectangle, using a GraphicsPath for the shape to set the Graphics.Clip property.  But you'll probably say, "that's not *quite* what I want".

Comment: Actually, using a PathGradientBrush(points[] and its SurroundColors one gets reall close, esp. if the polygon is regular..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around with Hans' idea of using a path filling, I think this will actually be the best way to solve this.

However neither a `GraphicsPath` nor `Clipping` nor the bounding rectangle are used. Instead we use a special overload that takes a point array; those points are matched with the `SurroundColors` property of a `PathGradientBrush`; this way the colors don't change radially as usually but stay pinned to the corner points..

Here are six examples:

[image][image][image][image][image]
[image]

The Color list is not exactly taken from a spectrum:

```
List<Color> colors = new List<Color>()
    { Color.Blue, Color.Lime, Color.Red, Color.Magenta , Color.MediumOrchid,
      Color.MediumSeaGreen, Color.LightSeaGreen, Color.LightSteelBlue, Color.DarkCyan};
```

and I use a simple structure to hold a `Point` and a `Color`:

```
struct cPoint
{
    public Point pt; 
    public Color col;
    public cPoint(int x, int y, Color c)
    { pt = new Point(x,y); col = c;}
}
```

My form has a `PictureBox` and a `NumericUpDown`. The NuD calls the `pictureBox.Paint`:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

..which calls two functions:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    points = getPolyList(colors.Take( (int) numericUpDown1.Value).ToList(),
                         pictureBox2.ClientSize);
    DrawPolyGradient(e.Graphics, points, pictureBox2.ClientRectangle);
}
```

The list of `cPoints` is created with simple trigonometry, which works fine for regular polygons:

```
List<cPoint> getPolyList(List<Color> colors, Size size)
{
    int number = colors.Count;
    List<cPoint> cPoints = new List<cPoint>();

    int x2 = size.Width / 2;
    int y2 = size.Height / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        double a = Math.PI / 180f * (i * 360d / number - 90);
        int x = x2 + (int)( Math.Cos(a) * (x2 - 15)); // don't overdraw
        int y = y2 + (int)( Math.Sin(a) * (x2 - 15)); // don't overdraw
        cPoints.Add(new cPoint(x, y, colors[i]));
    }
    return cPoints;
}
```

The drawing code is in a function of its own:

```
void DrawPolyGradient(Graphics G,  List<cPoint> cPoints, Rectangle bounds)
{
    int r = 0; int g = 0; int b = 0; int c = cPoints.Count;
    foreach (Color col in cPoints.Select(x => x.col))
    { r += col.R; g += col.G; b += col.B; }
    Color centercolor = Color.FromArgb(r / c, r / c, r / c);

    PathGradientBrush brush = new PathGradientBrush(cPoints.Select(x => x.pt).ToArray());

    brush.CenterPoint = new PointF(bounds.Width / 2, bounds.Height / 2);
    brush.CenterColor = centercolor;

    brush.SurroundColors = cPoints.Select(x => x.col).ToArray();

    G.FillRectangle(brush, bounds);
}
```

- It starts with calculating the `CenterColor`
- And setting the `CenterPoint`
- Next it creates a special `PathGradientBrush` using an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ak5y5sf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that does not take a `GraphicsPath` but a `Point` array!
- These points will correspond to the `SurroundColors` of the brush.

Especially the larger numbers could not be produced by my first idea of connecting the points along the edges with a simple `LinearGradientBrush`. Many of those lines would miss the influence of the corners in between.

Answer (score 0):

Can't add a comment so adding a minor fix to @TaW solution:

`Color centercolor = Color.FromArgb(r / c, r / c, r / c);`

Should be

`Color centercolor = Color.FromArgb(r / c, g / c, b / c);`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21160473)

Comment: @JoelC There's nothing wrong with referring to another answer, pointing out fixes or optimizations. Even if the user did have the privilege to comment, code is better to read in an answer of its own.