# Draw CIE color Space in MSchart

Tags: c#, mschart

I have a `6300 * 5` array with:

- Columns `1,2` = CIE data
- Columns `3,4,5` = S R G B

How should I Draw this in MsChart?

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the data from?

Comment: I have added a screenshot using 6.2k points from a CIE image.

Comment: please send me your data. my email: Amingalvani.kamran@gmail.com

Comment: formated and changed text briefly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

- Add `DataPoints` with `Markers` in the respective `Colors`
- Add `Annotations`
- Use one of the `xxxPaint` events

With only 6500 points you can't really fill the area by setting single pixels. So you better use a `FillElipse` call for each point.

If you use the `Pre`- or `PostPaint` event you will need to use the AxisX/Y methods `ValueToPixelPosition` for calculating the pixel coordinates from the CIE values.

In any case you set the `Minimum` and `Maximum` for both `Axes`.

Also you will need to calculate either the `Markers`' or the `Annotations`' or the ellipses' size from the chart's `ClientSize` to avoid ugly gaps in the colored area.

If you want to use DataPoints set the ChartType = Point and use this function for each of your data:

```
DataPoint Cie2DataPoint(float x, float y, float r, float g, float b)
{
    var dp = new DataPoint(x, y);
    dp.Color = Color.FromArgb((int)(256 * r), (int)(256 * g),(int)(256 * b));
    dp.MarkerColor = dp.Color;
    return dp;
}
```

Here are examples of helper function:

```
int MarkerSize(Chart chart, int count)
{
    return Math.Max(chart.ClientSize.Width, chart.ClientSize.Height )/ count + 1
}

void Rescale(Chart chart)
{
    Series s = chart3.Series[0];
    s.MarkerSize = MarkerSize(chart3, (int)Math.Sqrt(s.Points.Count));
}
```

The former takes an estimate of how many plot points you expect per axis; you may need to experiment a little. The next one assumes the points are actually filling a square; also that you only have one `ChartArea`.

This should also be modified for your data!

We need to rescale the sizes when  the Chart is resized:

```
private void chart3_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rescale (sender as Chart);
}
```

Here is an example of setting it up with a calculated set of data. You should loop over your list of data instead..:

```
Series s = chart3.Series[0];
s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
s.MarkerSize = 3;
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
   for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
   {
        s.Points.Add(Cie2DataPoint(x/100f, y/100f, x/100f, y/100f, (x+y)/200f));
   }

ChartArea ca = chart3.ChartAreas[0];
ca.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
ca.AxisY.Minimum = 0;
ca.AxisX.Maximum = 1;
ca.AxisY.Maximum = 1;
ca.AxisX.Interval = 0.1f;
ca.AxisY.Interval = 0.1f;
ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "0.00";
ca.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "0.00";

Rescale(chart3);
```

Result:

[image]

After grabbing ~6k colors from a CIE color chart the result looks rather grainy but basically correct:

[image]

Note that you probably need to allow for the reversed y-axis somehow; I simply subtracted my y-values from 0.9f. Use your own numbers!

Comment: thank you a lot , very helpful . but I have a problem my point can't fill the areas,how I fill?

Comment: Well valid they may be, but maybe a little  incomplete? There seem to be no data for the pink portion, nor for clear yellows? And they also seem to be somewhat unevenly spread.. Where do you get them from? Can I access them to play with them?

Comment: One way to fill in sparse areas would be to give up on DataPoints and Markers and go for Drawing with a LinearGradientBrush. But this really somewhat defies the idea of representing CIE color space as it will create color mixes in a somewhat linear way. And getting it to actually fille the area is also rather tricky. See [here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339553/fill-panel-with-gradient-in-three-colors/30341521?s=3|0.5582#30341521)  that fills a square with 4 interpolated colors..

Comment: The above link cold be expanded to fill a polygon, but having suitable data and knowing how they are layed out is still a prerequisite.