# HSV triangle in C#

Tags: c#, system.drawing

For my assignment I need to make to make a color picker that looks like this:

[image: img]

I've got the wheel part but can't figure out how to draw the triangle.

Comment: Probably [`DrawImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/558kfzex) should be sufficient.

Comment: You could pre-fabricate a semi-transparent triangle and draw that on top of a solid color.

Comment: have you tried any this yet??if yes then please add your code..

Comment: You may want to  look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339553/fill-panel-with-gradient-in-three-colors/30341521?s=5|0.0000#30341521) but you may want to include a set of hsv functions.

Comment: @Uwe: he needs a color __picker__ so the triangle must be created from its top corner..

Comment: @TaW Unfortunately I can't use brushes.

Comment: OK, so what can you use??

Comment: @TaW basically I can't use graphics methods like DrawPolygon

Comment: ok, but what __can__ you use???

Comment: @TaW anything but that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

void Main()
{
    double hue = 3.3;
    double sat = 0.4;
    double val = 0.9;

    var wheel = new ColorPicker(400);
    var img = wheel.DrawImage(hue, sat, val);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    {
        var pen = val < 0.5 ? Pens.White : Pens.Black;

        var wheelPosition = wheel.GetWheelPosition(hue);
        g.DrawEllipse(pen, (float)wheelPosition.X - 5, (float)wheelPosition.Y - 5, 10, 10);

        var trianglePosition = wheel.GetTrianglePosition(sat, val);
        g.DrawEllipse(pen, (float)trianglePosition.X - 5, (float)trianglePosition.Y - 5, 10, 10);
    }

    img.Dump(); // LINQPad extension method
}

public class ColorPicker
{
    public int Size { get; }

    public int CenterX => Size / 2;
    public int CenterY => Size / 2;
    public int InnerRadius => Size * 5 / 12;
    public int OuterRadius => Size / 2;

    public ColorPicker(int size = 400)
    {
        Size = size;
    }

    public enum Area
    {
        Outside,
        Wheel,
        Triangle
    }

    public struct PickResult
    {
        public Area Area { get; set; }
        public double? Hue { get; set; }
        public double? Sat { get; set; }
        public double? Val { get; set; }
    }

    public PickResult Pick(double x, double y)
    {
        var distanceFromCenter = Math.Sqrt((x - CenterX) * (x - CenterX) + (y - CenterY) * (y - CenterY));
        var sqrt3 = Math.Sqrt(3);
        if (distanceFromCenter > OuterRadius)
        {
            // Outside
            return new PickResult { Area = Area.Outside };
        }
        else if (distanceFromCenter > InnerRadius)
        {
            // Wheel
            var angle = Math.Atan2(y - CenterY, x - CenterX) + Math.PI / 2;
            if (angle < 0) angle += 2 * Math.PI;
            var hue = angle;
            return new PickResult { Area = Area.Wheel, Hue = hue };
        }
        else
        {
            // Inside
            var x1 = (x - CenterX) * 1.0 / InnerRadius;
            var y1 = (y - CenterY) * 1.0 / InnerRadius;
            if (0 * x1 + 2 * y1 > 1) return new PickResult { Area = Area.Outside };
            else if (sqrt3 * x1 + (-1) * y1 > 1) return new PickResult { Area = Area.Outside };
            else if (-sqrt3 * x1 + (-1) * y1 > 1) return new PickResult { Area = Area.Outside };
            else
            {
                // Triangle
                var sat = (1 - 2 * y1) / (sqrt3 * x1 - y1 + 2);
                var val = (sqrt3 * x1 - y1 + 2) / 3;

                return new PickResult { Area = Area.Triangle, Sat = sat, Val = val };
            }
        }
    }

    public Image DrawImage(double hue = 0.0, double sat = 1.0, double val = 1.0)
    {
        var img = new Bitmap(Size, Size, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        for (int y = 0; y < Size; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Size; x++)
            {
                Color color;
                var result = Pick(x, y);
                if (result.Area == Area.Outside)
                {
                    // Outside
                    color = Color.Transparent;
                }
                else if (result.Area == Area.Wheel)
                {
                    // Wheel
                    color = HSV(result.Hue.Value, sat, val, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Triangle
                    color = HSV(hue, result.Sat.Value, result.Val.Value, 1);
                }
                img.SetPixel(x, y, color);
            }
        }

        return img;
    }

    private Color HSV(double hue, double sat, double val, double alpha)
    {
        var chroma = val * sat;
        var step = Math.PI / 3;
        var interm = chroma * (1 - Math.Abs((hue / step) % 2.0 - 1));
        var shift = val - chroma;
        if (hue < 1 * step) return RGB(shift + chroma, shift + interm, shift + 0, alpha);
        if (hue < 2 * step) return RGB(shift + interm, shift + chroma, shift + 0, alpha);
        if (hue < 3 * step) return RGB(shift + 0, shift + chroma, shift + interm, alpha);
        if (hue < 4 * step) return RGB(shift + 0, shift + interm, shift + chroma, alpha);
        if (hue < 5 * step) return RGB(shift + interm, shift + 0, shift + chroma, alpha);
        return RGB(shift + chroma, shift + 0, shift + interm, alpha);
    }

    private Color RGB(double red, double green, double blue, double alpha)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb(
            Math.Min(255, (int)(alpha * 256)),
            Math.Min(255, (int)(red * 256)),
            Math.Min(255, (int)(green * 256)),
            Math.Min(255, (int)(blue * 256)));
    }

    public PointD GetWheelPosition(double hue)
    {
        double middleRadius = (InnerRadius + OuterRadius) / 2;
        return new PointD
        {
            X = CenterX + middleRadius * Math.Sin(hue),
            Y = CenterY - middleRadius * Math.Cos(hue)
        };
    }

    public PointD GetTrianglePosition(double sat, double val)
    {
        var sqrt3 = Math.Sqrt(3);
        return new PointD
        {
            X = CenterX + InnerRadius * (2 * val - sat * val - 1) * sqrt3 / 2,
            Y = CenterY + InnerRadius * (1 - 3 * sat * val) / 2
        };
    }
}

public class PointD
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image: Color picker]

Comment: That works, thanks man!

Comment: Nice work.  Any idea how to retrieve the x,y from the the value and saturation ?

Comment: @Zyend See the updated code. The `Main` method is an example using the methods.

Comment: @MarkusJarderot Thank you so much for your update. You saved my day ;)

Comment: Hi Markus, is there any reference material you could point me towards to learn more about creating color wheels and triangle coordinates in more detail?

Comment: @JohnBale The color conversion if from [HSL and HSV (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV). The circle and triangle is derived using geometry and algebra. `GetWheelPosition()` and `GetTrianglePosition()` are the algebraic inverses of `Pick()`.

Comment: @MarkusJarderot Ahh that makes a lot of sense, the most confusing part for me was the derivation of the get functions but seeing as you literally just inverse the Pick() function algebraically provides clarity.

Comment: Hello @MarkusJarderot, could you please explain on [this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58222353/the-formulars-in-hsv-triangle#58222353) how did you find your mathematical formulas on your algorithm, please?

Comment: This seems strange `if (0 * x1 + 2 * y1 > 1)` cause `0 * x1` is always `0`, so you are just testing `2 * y1 > 1`.

Comment: I wrote it that way so that it resembles the other conditions (`a * x1 + b * y1 > 1`) to make it more readable. The compiler might optimize it to `2 * y1 > 1` with the appropriate flags.