# The formulars in HSV triangle

Tags: math, hsv

I do not know how the following two formulas are derived. Please kindly explain. My reputation point is so low that I can't ask the person who wrote the formula.

[HSV triangle in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531608/hsv-triangle-in-c-sharp)

```
var sat = (1 - 2*y1) / (sqrt3*x1 - y1 + 2);
var val = (sqrt3*x1 - y1 + 2) / 3;
```

Comment: I've asked the question for you :)

Comment: @0009laH Thank you! :'-)

Answer (score 1):

After the transformation, I needed the corners of the triangle to touch the unit circle at the points `<0,-1>` "top", `<-√3/2,1/2>` "bottom-left" and `<√3/2,1/2>` "bottom-right". I picked bottom-left to be the black point (*val* = 0), and when *val* = 1, the top would be the color point (*val* = 1 and *sat* = 1), and the bottom-right would be the white point (*val* = 1 and *sat* = 0).

To achieve this, I first defined the right edge as the equation

```
<x,y> = <0,-1>*sat + <√3/2,1/2>*(1-sat)
        ^            ^-- When sat = 0, the result is this point
        '-- When sat = 1, the result is this point
```

I then scaled this line towards `<-√3/2,1/2>` when *val* goes to zero

```
<x,y> = ( <0,-1>*sat + <√3/2,1/2>*(1-sat) )*val + <-√3/2,1/2>*(1-val)
<x,y> = <0,-1>*sat*val + <√3/2,1/2>*(1-sat)*val + <-√3/2,1/2>*(1-val)
        ^                ^                        ^-- When val = 0, the result is this point
        |                '-- When val = 1 and sat = 0, the result is this point
        '-- When val = 1 and sat = 1, the result is this point
```

Converting from vector form:

```
x = 0*sat*val + √3/2*(1-sat)*val + -√3/2*(1-val)
y = -1*sat*val + 1/2*(1-sat)*val + 1/2*(1-val)
```

Expanding:

```
x = -√3/2*val*sat + √3*val - √3/2
y = -3/2*val*sat + 1/2
```

Rearranging:

```
(√3*x - y + 2)/3 = val
(1 - 2*y)/3 = sat*val
```

Solving for *sat* and *val*:

```
sat = (1 - 2*y)/(√3*x - y + 2)
val = (√3*x - y + 2)/3
```

Comment: Thank you guys all! This will help me a lot.
I've been trying to understand this formulas for a month.
It's still not easy though :-), but I'll try to finish it.

Comment: Finally I understand those formulars. Your explanation was clear and enough. My mathematical knowledge isn't enough, so I was able to study it again, thanks to your formulars. What about make a mathematics lesson for software programmers?  :-) Thanks again!